# Hue and Solr - How to rename fields in Hue for display purposes

Tags: cloudera, hue

I have Cloudera 5.7 ecosystem, i use Solr and Hue,
in Solr i have fields like `srcName` `postTtl`

I want it will display in Hue as `SourceName` and `PostTitle` without touching Solr.

Is Hue has some configuration that i can change display names ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Hue you can rename the main title of the widget which is based on the main selected field. But in the field list, Hue is not doing any magic and list the fields as is from Solr.